# Can a trigger do a SELECT and see new values on a compound trigger, in "after statement"?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have a table t1, with two columns t1c1 and t1c2,
If an update is done on t1c1 or t1c2, I need to calculate a value and update the value on another table t2 (not used during the calculation)
This calculation need somes tables, including t1 (because the update of t1c1 or t1c2 can change the value, they are parameters of the calculation if you prefere...)
The problem is, do a SELECT on t1 cause a "mutation table error" because t1 is  the "event".
I can use "PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION" but, I have to "commit" in the trigger so if rollback, it's doesn't rollback my trigger operations...
And the line updated can't be seen which cause a wrong calculation...
Can I use "compound trigger", add in a variable data used "after each row", and do my calculation in the "after statement" ?
Can I see updates in "after statement" or only what is commited  ?
Can I don't commit in "after statement" in case of rollback modification t1c1 or t1c2 ?

Thank you very much and sorry for my English....

Comment: please try to format your question. It's hard to read.

Comment: Thanks Etienne Wattebled.  Compound triggers can be used in some situations where single-stage triggers are not feasible/performant.  But if all that is required is to perform a calculation based on the new (or old) values of t1c1 and t1c2, then no `SELECT on t1` should be required.  Can you elaborate on the situation?  Maybe provide the tables involved, with a desired example output?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In statement level trigger (i.e. one which has "for each row") add your key level information to a PL/SQL array.  I typically create a package to hold such PL/SQL arrays with functions to add rows etc. easily.

   2. Then in "after statement" (not each row) go through the PL/SQL array and do whatever you want - no restrictions here.  When done, reset the PL/SQL array so that it is empty for next use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Can you tell me if a "classic trigger for each row", is equivalent to an "compound trigger after each row" or  "compound trigger before each row" please  ?

Comment: "compound trigger" is an informal name for this concept.  All it is saying is that you are "compounding trigger executions" that is not an official term.  So you do a simple "create or replace trigger xxx on yyyy BEFORE EACH ROW" or "AFTER EACH ROW" to capture data into a PLSQL array and then you create another trigger which are termed "after statement" to traverse that PLSQL array and do your work.

Comment: The problem is, I have already an existing trigger create or replace XYZ after UPDATE OF .... ON ...... END XYZ which calls a procedure p1. So I would like to "merge" both triggers because we can not create 2 triggers with same event. Should I do put the call p1 in the compunded trigger in "AFTER EACH ROW" or "AFTER STATEMENT"  ? What is the equivalent of just after update for compound ? –

Comment: First you can create multiple triggers on the same event.  You cannot rely on ordering among them but having multiple triggers is no problem.  In EACH ROW add key to PLSQL array.  And make p1 traverse that PLSQL array.